# How to create a fatJar using "gradle build" command

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle, groovy

Please note that, We can create the fatJar using gradle fatJar, Here we want to create fatJar using gradle build command. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have 2 possible ways how to do it:

1) If you already have some "fatJar" task - you can add next configuration after "fatJar" task and it will create two jars after building command (regular and fat):

```
artifacts {
   archives fatJar
}
```

`fatJar` - it is your task name

2) If you will use such configuration - `fatJar` will be building with regular build command

```
jar {
   manifest {
       attributes (
            'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect {it.getName()}.join(' '),
            'Main-Class': 'com.test.MainClassName'
       )
   }
   from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```